# XPath contains(text(),'some string') doesn't work when used with node with more than one Text subnode

Tags: xml, xpath, dom4j

I have a small problem with XPath contains with dom4j ...

Let's say my XML is

```
<Home>
    <Addr>
        <Street>ABC</Street>
        <Number>5</Number>
        <Comment>BLAH BLAH BLAH <br/><br/>ABC</Comment>
    </Addr>
</Home>
```

Let's say I want to find all the nodes that have ABC in the text given the root Element...

So the XPath that I would needed to write would be

`//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]`

However this is not what dom4j returns .... is this a dom4j problem or my understanding how XPath works, since that query returns only the `Street` element and not the `Comment` element?

The DOM makes the `Comment` element a composite element with four tags two

```
[Text = 'XYZ'][BR][BR][Text = 'ABC']
```

I would assume that the query should still return the element since it should find the element and run contains on it, but it doesn't ...

The following query returns the element, but it returns far more then just the element – it returns the parent elements as well, which is undesirable to the problem.

```
//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]
```

Does any one know the XPath query that would return just the elements `<Street/>` and `<Comment/>` ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]` returns only the `<Street>` element. It doesn't return any ancestors of `<Street>` or `<Comment>`.

Comment: None of the answers addressed the different behavior found in new versions of XPath (versions 2.0 and above, starting in ~2007) so I've added an [updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085) to explain the difference.

Answer (score 992, accepted):

The `<Comment>` tag contains two text nodes and two `<br>` nodes as children.

Your xpath expression was

```
//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]
```

To break this down,

1. `*` is a selector that matches any element (i.e. tag) -- it returns a node-set.
2. The `[]` are a conditional that operates on each individual node in that node set. It matches if any of the individual nodes it operates on match the conditions inside the brackets.
3. `text()` is a *selector* that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context node -- it returns a node set.
4. `contains` is a function that operates on a string. If it is passed a node set, the node set is [converted into a string by returning the string-value  of the node in the node-set that is first in document order](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions). Hence, it can match only the first text node in your `<Comment>` element -- namely `BLAH BLAH BLAH`. Since that doesn't match, you don't get a `<Comment>` in your results.

You need to change this to

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'ABC')]]
```

1. `*` is a selector that matches any element (i.e. tag) -- it returns a node-set.
2. The outer `[]` are a conditional that operates on each individual node in that node set -- here it operates on each element in the document.
3. `text()` is a *selector* that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context node -- it returns a node set.
4. The inner `[]` are a conditional that operates on each node in that node set -- here each individual text node. Each individual text node is the starting point for any path in the brackets, and can also  be referred to explicitly as `.` within the brackets. It matches if any of the individual nodes it operates on match the conditions inside the brackets.
5. `contains` is a function that operates on a string. Here it is passed an individual text node (`.`). Since it is passed the second text node in the `<Comment>` tag individually, it will see the `'ABC'` string and be able to match it.

Comment: Awesome im a little bit of an xpath noob, so let me get this, text() is a function that takes the expression contains(.,'ABC'), Is there a chance you can explain so i don't do this kinda stupid stuff again ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a long explanation. I don't really know that much about XPath myself -- I just experimented a bit until I stumbled on that combination. Once I had a working combination, I made a guess what was going on and looked in the [XPath standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to confirm what I thought was going on and write the explanation.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but can anyone comment on if there is a fundamental difference, preferably with some simple test cases between the answer given by Ken Bloom and `//*[contains(., 'ABC')]`. I had always used the pattern given by Mike Milkin, thinking it was more appropriate, but just doing `contains` on the current context seems to actually be what I want more often.

Comment: how to use the regular expression here.lets say my text is "Result(1)" and the number is not constant it may be any number.So how to use 
//*[contains( text(),'ABC'] ??

i had tried below but not returning anything

//*[contains( text(),' Result ("+".*"+")" ' )]

Comment: @Zack for case insensitive search use //*[text([contains(translate(., 'ABC', 'abc'), 'abc')]]

Comment: Can you, after all, explain how your solution is different from `//*[contains(.,'ABC')]`? Because this one seems to work as well.

Comment: I see now, [`text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#location-paths) returns all text nodes of the current node (node-set). But when `contains()` gets [applied](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#section-Function-Calls) its first argument gets converted by a [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string) function. That takes the first node and returns its [`string-value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#dt-string-value). That is, `//*[contains(.,'ABC')]` takes into account only the first text node.

Comment: ...`//*[text()[contains(.,'ABC')]]` means any element for which `text()[contains(.,'ABC')]` is [`true`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates). `text()[contains(.,'ABC')]` is a node-set of all text node children of the context node for which `contains(.,'ABC')` is `true`. Since `text()[contains(.,'ABC')]` is a node-set, it's converted to boolean by [`boolean()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-boolean) function. For a node-set, `boolean()` returns `true` if it's not empty.

Comment: ...That is, `//*[text()[contains(.,'ABC')]]` means any element, which has at least one text node child, that contains `ABC`. Which means `//*[contains(.,'BLAH ABC')]` won't match anything. Now then, `//*[contains(., 'ABC')]` supposedly means any element that contains `ABC`. Here when converting to a string the context node is supposedly treated as a [node-set](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string). So, its [`string-value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#dt-string-value) is taken, which is basically all its text.

Comment: ...As such, `//*[contains(.,'BLAH ABC')]` matches elements `Home`, `Addr`, and `Comment`.

Comment: @x-yuri You helped me understand, your second comment was the most explanatory: *is a node-set of all text node **CHILDREN** of the context node*. Thankful!

Comment: Since this answer has a high score and is likely to be widely seen, let me clarify that it relates to XPath 1.0 and not to later versions of the language. From XPath 2.0 (which came out in 2007) `//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]` will throw an error if there is an element with more than one text node. This change was made to prevent the problem described in this answer.

Comment: What's the difference between `contain` and `=` like:
//*[text()='ABC']? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelKay, As of Aug,2023, Python3.10+selenium4.11 seem to expose this problem. `[contains(text(), 'ABC')]` and `[text()[contains(., 'ABC')] return different results without an error.  Xpath2.0 may not be broadly adopted.

Comment: @DanLocks You are right that there are many people still using XPath 1.0 because that's often what's available "out of the box" with generic tools for Java, .NET, Python, and Javascript. XML specialists are much more likely to be using tools that support later XPath versions, which require installation of third-party libraries.

Answer (score 26):

The XML document:

```
<Home>
    <Addr>
        <Street>ABC</Street>
        <Number>5</Number>
        <Comment>BLAH BLAH BLAH <br/><br/>ABC</Comment>
    </Addr>
</Home>
```

The XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'ABC')]
```

`//*` matches any [descendant element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#location-paths) of the [root node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#path-abbrev). That is, any element but the root node.

`[...]` is a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates), it filters the node-set. It returns nodes for which `...` is `true`:

> A predicate filters a node-set [...] to produce a new node-set. For each node in the node-set to be filtered, the PredicateExpr is evaluated [...]; if PredicateExpr evaluates to true for that node, the node is included in the new node-set; otherwise, it is not included.

`contains('haystack', 'needle')` returns `true` if `haystack` [contains](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-contains) `needle`:

> Function: boolean contains(string, string)
>
> The contains function returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false.

But `contains()` takes a string as its first parameter. And it's passed nodes. To deal with that every node or node-set passed as the first parameter is [converted](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#section-Function-Calls) to a string by the `string()` function:

> An argument is converted to type string as if by calling the string function.

`string()` function returns `string-value` of [the first node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

`string-value` of an [element node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#element-nodes):

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

`string-value` of a [text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#section-Text-Nodes):

> The string-value of a text node is the character data.

So, basically `string-value` is all text that is contained in a node (concatenation of all descendant text nodes).

[`text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-tests) is a node test that matches any text node:

> The node test text() is true for any text node. For example, child::text() will select the text node children of the context node.

Having that said, `//*[contains(text(), 'ABC')]` matches any element (but the root node), the first text node of which contains `ABC`. Since `text()` returns a node-set that contains all child text nodes of the context node (relative to which an expression is evaluated). But `contains()` takes only the first one. So for the document above the path matches the `Street` element.

The following expression `//*[text()[contains(., 'ABC')]]` matches any element (but the root node), that has at least one child text node, that contains `ABC`. `.` represents the context node. In this case, it's a child text node of any element but the root node. So for the document above the path matches the `Street`, and the `Comment` elements.

Now then, `//*[contains(., 'ABC')]` matches any element (but the root node) that contains `ABC` (in the concatenation of the descendant text nodes). For the document above it matches the `Home`, the `Addr`, the `Street`, and the `Comment` elements. As such, `//*[contains(., 'BLAH ABC')]` matches the `Home`, the `Addr`, and the `Comment` elements.

Comment: Like the accepted answer, this answer relates only to XPath 1.0. The situation with XPath 2.0 (released 2007) and later versions is different.

Comment: Right, this answer pertains to XPath 1.0.  See my [modern (2022) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085) that explains how XPath 2.0 and later behave differently.

Answer (score 24):

<sup>***Modern answer that covers XPath 1.0 vs XPath 2.0+ behavior ...***</sup>

This XPath,

```
//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]
```

behaves differently with XPath 1.0 and later versions of XPath (2.0+).

### Common behavior

- `//*` selects all elements within a document.
- `[]` filters those elements according to the predicate expressed therein.
- `contains(string, substring)` within the predicate will filter those elements for which `substring` is a *substring* in `string`.

### XPath 1.0 behavior

- `contains(arg1, substring)`: If the first argument evaluates to a *node set*, `contains()` will convert the node set to a *string* by taking the string value of the ***first node in the node set***.  (If `arg1` is `text()`, only the first of all matching `text` nodes will be considered by `contains()`.)  If you find this odd, you are not alone.
- For `//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]` that node set will be all child text nodes of each element in the document.
- Since ***only the first text node child is used***, the expectation that all child text nodes are tested for `'ABC'` substring containment is violated.
- This leads to counter-intuitive results to anyone unfamiliar with the above conversion rules.

[XPath 1.0 online example](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVb8) shows that only one `'ABC'` is selected.

### XPath 2.0+ behavior

- It is an error to call `contains(arg1, substring)` with a sequence of more than one item as the first argument.
- This corrected the counter-intuitive behavior described above in XPath 1.0.

[XPath 2.0 online example](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNP54ea) shows a typical error message due to the conversion error particular to XPath 2.0+.

### Common solutions

1. If you wish to include descendent elements (beyond children), test against the [*string value*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of an element as a single string, rather than the individual string values of the child text nodes, this XPath,

   ```
   //*[contains(.,'ABC')]
   ```

   selects your targeted `Street` and `Comment` elements and also their `Addr` and `Home` ancestor elements because those too have `'ABC'` as substrings of their string values.

   [Online example](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NKS) shows ancestors being selected too.
2. If you wish to exclude descendent elements (beyond children), this XPath,

   ```
   //*[text()[contains(.,'ABC')]]
   ```

   selects only your targeted `Street` and `Comment` because only those elements have text node children whose string values contain the `'ABC'` substring.  This will be true for all versions of XPath

   [Online example](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MXNWNU) shows only `Street` and `Comment` being selected.

Answer (score 8):

`[contains(text(),'')]` only returns true or false. It won't return any element results.

Comment: this wont work if i had '  '  or '     '  how can we trim ?

Comment: `contains(text(),'JB-')` is not work! `conatains` takes **two strings** as arguments - `contains(**string**, **string**)`! text() **is not string**, is a function!

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer will return all the parent nodes too. To get only the actual nodes with ABC even if the string is after 
:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'ABC')]]/text()[contains(.,"ABC")]
```

Comment: Incase if  someone curios to get parent element of text node instead;
 post-fix query with `/..` like so: `//*[text()[contains(.,'ABC')]]/text()[contains(.,"ABC")]/..` 
Thanks! @roger

Answer (score 5):

```
//*[text()='ABC']
```

returns

```
<street>ABC</street>
<comment>BLAH BLAH BLAH <br><br>ABC</comment>
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a nine year old question with five existing answers it is very important to point out what unique new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Comment: Answer I posted was very simple. So thought like sharing, which may help beginners like me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way to match nodes which contain a given text string.  First query for the text node itself, then get the parent:

```
//text()[contains(., "ABC")]/..
```

For me this is easy to read and understand.