# Xpath - How to select subnode where sibling-node contains certain text

Tags: xpath, subtree

I want to use XPath to select the sub tree containing the `<name>`-tag with "ABC" and not the other one from the following xml. Is this possible? And as a minor question, which keywords would I use to find something like that over Google (e.g. for selecting the sub tree by an attribute I would have the terminology for)?

```
<root>
  <operation>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <description>Description 1</description>
  </operation>
  <operation>
    <name>DEF</name>
    <description>Description 2</description>
  </operation>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/operation[name='ABC']
```

**For your second question**: I strongly recommend *not* to rely on online sources (there are some that aren't so good) but to read a good book on XPath.

**See some resources listed here**: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I think a more accurate way to do it would be:
`//operation[./name[text()='ABC']]`.
And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more) , we can also make it:
`//operation[./name[text()[.='ABC']]]`