# Can't select label by text when label contains more than text

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am driving myself bonkers with this.

I have three form fields in a form:

1. Customer: required dropdown field
2. Weight: required text field
3. Status: optional text field

Each element has that label.  The required fields' labels contain a span with an asterisk.

I'm using Xpather in Chrome.  When I search for this, I receive 2 results, when I should get 3:

```
//*[contains(text(),'t')]
```

This makes no sense to me At All.

Customer, which is working:

```
<label for='customer-field'>
  <span class='required-marker'>*</span>
  Customer
  <input id='customer-field' type='text' />
</label>
```

Weight, which is **not** working:

```
<label class='control-label'>
  <span id='ctl01_requiredMarker' class='required-marker'>*</span>
  Weight
</label>
```

Status, which is working:

```
<label class='control-label'>
  Status
</label>
```

The only workaround that works for me is removing the required marker from the Weight label container.  However, that doesn't explain how "Customer" gets matched at all.

Noteworthy: I'm trying to automate testing this page, so I can't really remove that span tag.

What's going on?  And/or what do I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing your XPath to the following:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'t')]]
```

The [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more) of this fix breaks it down far better than I could've done, so refer to that for detailed explanation! I've tested it myself using the XPath Checker extension for Firefox, and it matches your three items.

Comment: It works!! Bless you a thousand times, this has blocked me for FOREVER.

Comment: I read the explanation from the source, and I still don't really understand it, but this did work for me, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below method

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='required-marker']/..")).getText().contains("Weight")

Please Let me know above method is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your html is where the issue lies.

This is probably what your html should look like:

```
<span class='required-marker'>*
    <label for='customer-field'>Customer</label>
    <input id='customer-field' type='text' />
</span>
<span id='ctl01_requiredMarker' class='required-marker'>*
    <label class='control-label'>Weight</label>
</span>
<label class='control-label'>Status</label>
```

Comment: This works as expected. Unfortunately, he mentioned not being able to remove the span tag, so I don't think he'll be able to use this.

Comment: @Tetrinity Sure, but I think it's a bug in the HTML, as in the HTML itself needs to be correctly written.

Comment: The original HTML is all over the place, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Selenium` or `WebDriver`? What does `WebDriver` return as a response? Also make sure you add a "." before the xpath like `.//*[contains(text(),'t')]`

What does this print?

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'t')]"));
s.o.p(elements.size());
```