# Nokogiri XPATH - get range of nodes based on a search key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have an html file with some paragraphs as below:

```
<p> paragraph 1 </p>
<p> paragraph 2 </p>
<p> paragraph 3 </p>
<p> paragraph 4 </p>
```

Now I want to get the first two or three of the above paragraphs.

The snippet below only returns one paragraph based on the index I define..

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('test.html'))
p doc.xpath('//p[1][contains(text(), "paragraph")]')
```

but I want a range of paragraphs like `1..2` how can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code as below

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('test.html'))
puts doc.xpath("//p[position() >= 1 and position() <= 3][contains(.,'paragraph')]")
```

**output**

```
paragraph 1 
paragraph 2 
paragraph 3
```

Read this [`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)

> The `position` function returns a number equal to the *context position* from the expression evaluation context.

and [`EqualityExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-EqualityExpr).

Comment: @tokhi It is a short form.. Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more)