# Selenium web driver getting the text from the for attribute of a label using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath

I have seen some examples of  how to do this in Javascript or python, but am looking for how to find the text of the for attribute on a label. e.g.

```
<label for="thisIsTheTextNeeded">LabelText</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id=thisIsTheTextNeeded">
```

We want to pick up the text from the for attribute on the label element. Then use that text as the id to find the checkbox.

The .NET solution might look like:

```
textWeNeed = selenium.getAttribute("//label[text()='LabelText']/@for");
```

I tried this in Ruby:

```
textWeNeed =
@browser.find_element("xpath//label[text()='LabelText']/@for")
```

and get the error:

> expected "xpath//label[text()=input_value]/@for":String to respond to #shift (ArgumentError)

Any ideas?

Comment: Found these good resource for path syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more and http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the *attribute* method to get the value of the attribute. See the [doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings)

```
element = @browser.find_element(:xpath, "//label[text()='LabelText']")
attrValue = element.attribute("for")
```

According to OP's comment and provided html I think the element needs some *explicit* wait

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds

element = wait.until { @browser.find_element(:xpath => "//label[contains(text(),'My list name')]") }
attrValue = element.attribute("for")
```

Comment: I think I am closer, but not quite there. Thanks.

Comment: @LauraHannahVachon I see **Typo** in in xpath. It should be **LabelText** not *LaelText* correct?

Comment: The given selector //label[text()="LabelText"] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
      InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //label[text()="LabelText"] because of the following error:
      [Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "<unknown>"] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)

Comment: Can you provide the actual html of the element?

Comment: element = @browser.find_element(:xpath, "//label[text()=#{input_value}]")
          attrValue = element.attribute("for")
          listCheckboxPtr = @browser.find_element(:id, attrValue)

Comment: <label for="aGroupIds-191245">150326121726681 My list name</label>

Comment: Is that the label you want ?

Comment: Yes, I need to find that label and get the text of the for. Then use that ID to find a checkbox with the id

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it. Thanks for all the help!

```
element = @browser.find_element(:xpath=>"//label[text()=\'#{input_value}\']")
attrValue = element.attribute('for') listElement =
@browser.find_element(:id=>"#{attrValue}")
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` function requires `Hash` to search with xpath.

correct way is here,

```
textWeNeed =
@browser.find_element(xpath: "xpath//label[text()='LabelText']/@for")
```

below is wrong way(your code).

```
textWeNeed =
@browser.find_element("xpath//label[text()='LabelText']/@for")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in Ruby when looking for Strings best to use is :find: instead of :find_element:

`textWeNeed =
@browser.find("xpath//label[text()='LabelText']/@for")`

when presented with the error: "String to respond to #shift"