# CasperJS' getElementsByXpath returns null with valid XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I m scraping soccer scores data from website. All scores are in a table, every `<tr>` has "block home matches 17" and some unique stuff after it.

I tested my xpath in the Chrome dev tools, it recognizes only the table rows I need.

```js
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create();
var xpath = require('casper').selectXPath;
var result = [];

function getScores(){
    console.log("getting scores");
    result = __utils__.getElementsByXPath("//tr[contains(@id,'block_home_matches_17')");
}

casper.start('http://int.soccerway.com/', function() {
    console.log("casper start....");       
    var l = getScores();
    utils.dump(l);
});

casper.run();
```

The code returns [] as utils.dump! Why? my xpath is valid!

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems:

- You can only access DOM nodes in the sandboxed page context through [`evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate), but
- You can't pass DOM nodes to the outside context (read the [PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)).
- The [clientutils (`__utils__`) module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html) is only available in the page context.

You can **retrieve a *representation* of your targeted DOM nodes** either through CasperJS functions:

```js
casper.start('http://int.soccerway.com/', function() {
    utils.dump(this.getElementsInfo(xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'block_home_matches_17')")));
});
```

or by directly working on the elements in the page context:

```js
casper.start('http://int.soccerway.com/', function() {
    utils.dump(this.evaluate(function(){
        return __utils__.getElementsByXPath("//tr[contains(@id,'block_home_matches_17')").map(function(el){
            return {} // TODO: produce your own representation
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: Additionally, you're not returning anything from `getScores()` so `l` will always be null.