# Xpath isn't parsing php var correctly

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i am trying to extract data from XML with xpath and php,but the xpath command is not parsing the string php var,thus am not getting back any result
this is my php code

```
$term=$_POST["term"];
var_dump($term);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Dbase.xml');
echo "$term";
$Movies = $xml->xpath('/Database/Movie[contains(Title,'$term')]');

foreach($Movies as $Movie) {
echo "Found {$Movie->Title}<br />";
echo "Found {$Movie->Cast}<br />";
echo "Found {$Movie->Producer}<br />";
}
```

i forgot to mention that a previous page containing a post form sends the data( i will use to search) in the input named "term"

Comment: pls post the XML, valid, but minimum necessary.

Comment: Your xpath seems wrong, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more

Comment: `$Movies = $xml->xpath('//Database/Movie[contains(Title,"'.$term.'")]');` perhaps?

Comment: @RamRaider suggestion was great it works fine thanks,could you provide why it worked that way?

Comment: you were not using quotes correctly ( single quotes do not allow for the inclusion of a variable unless escaped ) and the query needs to begin with a double slash - unless you provide a root node for the search to operate from

Comment: i already have been answered by RamRaider,no need for the XML doc upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RamRaider posted this is the solution to my problem :

```
$Movies = $xml->xpath('//Database/Movie[contains(Title,"'.$term.'")]');
```

it is so because the quotes i used,were not operating correctly,so the variable was not parsed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your *$term* will be expanded inside a single quoted string. Try:

```
$Movies = $xml->xpath("/Database/Movie[contains(Title,'$term')]");
```