# Xpth extract plain email text

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the email text from a list but without success.
In particular I've used this code

```
//li/div/p//*[contains(., '@')]
```

but strangely it doesn't work! Could you help me?
Here's the code exemple

```
<li class="bgmp_list-item">
            <h3 class="bgmp_list-placemark-title">
                <a href="http://www.exemple.com" class=""> Name1 </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="bgmp_list-description">
                <p class="">
                    <strong class="">Responsible:</strong> John Doe                      <br>
                    <strong class="">Site:</strong> <a title="www.exemple.com" href="http://www.exemple.com" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','www.2ld.it']);" target="_blank" class="">www.2ld.it</a>
                    <br>
                    <strong class="">Email:</strong> some_email@email.com                        
        <br><strong class="">Address:</strong> <a href="http://www.exemple.com" target="_blank" class="">3, Main Street 00000, London</a>                        <br>
                    <strong>Tel:</strong> 00 000000 <strong>Fax:</strong> 0000000                    
        </p>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there but not quite. For the sample code the correct xpath would be

```
//p/text()[contains(.,'@')]
```

Not to reinvent the wheel here is a very good explanation on it on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more)

Comment: Correct XPath (+1), but the linked answer doesn't provide relevant explanation on why OP's initial XPath doesn't work while this one work. Notice that the following form of XPath which OP uses `//*[contains(.,'ABC')]` doesn't suffer the same problem as `//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]`

Answer (score 0):

By using `p//*[contains(., '@')]` you apply the predicate on individual *child elements of `<p>`*, while there is no such *child element* because
the target email address text is direct child of `<p>`. This is one of the reason why the intial XPath didn't work. Applying the predicate on `<p>` directly should work :

```
//li/div/p[contains(., '@')]
```

but that will return the `<p>` element. If you need to return only the text node that contains email address, then the predicate should be applied on individual text nodes within `<p>`, as mentioned in the other answer :

```
//li/div/p/text()[contains(., '@')]
```