# Xpath expression for text that contains a certain string

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

On the website http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/redditinc/reddit/reddit-1-5-5-release/reddit-1-5-5-android-apk-download/, I'm trying to extract the lines containing the `Min:` and `Target:` versions of Android (see screenshot below).

[image]

In the Scrapy shell, so far I've come up with the XPath expression

```
In [1]: android_version = response.xpath('//*[@title="Android version"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]')
```

such that if I concatenate with `.//text()` and `extract()`, I get several lines including the ones I want:

```
In [2]: android_version_text = android_version.xpath('.//text()').extract()

In [3]: android_version_text
Out[3]: 
[u'\n',
 u'Min: Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich MR1, API 15) ',
 u'\n',
 u'Target: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow, API 23)',
 u'\n']
```

I would now like to refine the XPath expression to get only fields with `text()` containing `"Min:"` or `"Target:`. Following [XPath contains(text(),'some string') doesn't work when used with node with more than one Text subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more), I've tried

```
In [7]: android_version.xpath('.//*[contains(text(), "Min:"]')
```

but this gives rise to a

```
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in .//*[contains(text(), "Min:"]
```

How could I construct an XPath expression to get only the `Min:` line, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Following https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/07/17/xpath-tips-from-the-web-scraping-trenches/, I came up with the following:

```
In [12]: android_min_version = response.xpath('//*[@title="Android version"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()[starts-with(., "Min:")]')

In [13]: android_min_version.extract()
Out[13]: [u'Min: Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich MR1, API 15) ']
```

in short, to filter the text you want you do an ordinary `//text()` followed by a `[contains(., "target_string")]`, where `"target_string"` is the string you are searching. (Here I have also used `starts-with` instead of `contains`).