# Selenium Robot Framework Web Locator

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to find an element that RF can locate. I tried Click Element, Click Link, and Mouse Down with now luck.

```
<a class="navHREF " href="#" onclick="return swap_interior_nav('6');">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" id="span_1_6"></span>
    Inventory
</a>
```

I have tried the below XPath and can’t seem to make it work

```
//a[contains(.,'Inventory')]
```

I can make it work with below, however, this link dynamic based on user permissions so the order can change of this function.

```
html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[6]/a
```

Comment: what is the problem? element not found? Element not clickable? Stale element? Syntax error?

Comment: Element was not visible in 5 seconds.. then I added a Sleep 3 and still same thing.

Comment: what's the exact exception? and if you select it by some other attribute (not text), e.g. `//a[contains(@onclick,'return swap_interior_nav')]`, does it get selected or you get the same exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was close and perhaps inspired from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more). The main issue you have is that your trying to access the first text node, whereas you need the second one. The below example works on the provided code.

```
//a[text()[contains(.,'Inventory')]]
```