# Click on li element searching specific displayed text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using python 3 and chrome driver. I'm trying to click on my desired element searching for the text displayed on this [page](https://www.milanuncios.com/publicar-anuncios-gratis/) . For example, in case of "BEBES" I'm using:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "BEBES")]'))).click()
```

but nothing happens. Just throws the time out exception. What's my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xPath` is not correct. Use this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(), "Bebes")]'))).click()
```

Note: upper/lowercase makes difference

[image: img1]

and

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

This post suggests using the following as text() returns a node set:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'BEBES')]]
```

[XPath contains(text(),'some string') doesn't work when used with node with more than one Text subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more)