# Pythno Selenium clicking list item within ui

Tags: python, selenium

I am working with python and selenium to click on the Photo/Video button on a facebook page. The HTML associated with this seems to have a list item (li) inside a ui. The html is as in the following image. The button circles is the one I am trying to press.

Can anyone please tell me how should I press the Photo/Video button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code?

I used the `xPath` method and `contains()` to compare the text in the div.

By the way, the found object does not have the `click` related function, and the click function seems to be a tag among its `parents`

The syntax for finding a parent in `xPath` is `/..` and I used this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655588/12582501

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),"Photo/Video")]/../../../a').click()
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but get the following message "Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (329, 634)"

Comment: I modified the code, can you check again? @UmarDastgir

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has an intresting thing: testids
With this IDs you can click all of clickable elements on the site

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="photo-video-button"]').click()
```

In this case you can exec your code, when on page will be another element with text "Photo/Video"

Comment: I tried this, but get the following message "Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (329, 634)"