# Selenium grabbing second instance of xpath with same div

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to grab the monthly cost estimate using xpath on selenium but I am having a hard time getting the right value as there are two and possibly more div classes that define property taxes or home insurance. I have my code currently running:

```
principal_and_interest = (driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sc-Rmtcm GNsVX"]/span[@class="Text-aiai24-0 cJeryq"]').text)
```

but after running it over different listings, I see that some listings use a different div class name (see pictures to compare). My question is how do I get it so that it either takes into account both (or more div cases) or ,even better, a way that will look for 'principal_and_interest' despite the div classes being different?

[div class for other listings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiHXI.png)

[div class for listings that works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc7AJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the **price** of `Principal & interest` try following **xpath**

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Principal & interest']/following-sibling::span").text)
```

---

To get list of prices based on `Principal & interest`

```
for price in driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Principal & interest']/following-sibling::span"):
    print(price.text)
```

Comment: That worked very well! Thank you! Can you explain the '/following-sibling::span' portion of the code so I can better understand this?

Comment: @Yual : `'/following-sibling::span` will identify the next span tag of the previous tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to grab the span with 'Principal and interest' text then you can try this

`//span[contains(.,'Principal & interest')]`

Comment: Thanks @Zmehak! Can you help me understand what the period in contains(. means?

Comment: @Yuanl read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more