# Xpath of weird A element with text in the quotation marks

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the element by xPath but the text is in the quotation marks and xPath does not work..

Any ideas?

Code when opened as HTML:

```
<li class="help-menu-item-486 active">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menuItemLink486">
<i id="id31" style="display:none" data-wicket-placeholder=""></i>
Archiv dokumentů
</a>
</li>
```

Code in the console:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

I even tried to add % so `%Archiv%` - but still no luck..

Comment: Maybe try //a[text()[contains(.,’Archiv’)]]. Reason: there are more text()-nodes in that a-element

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655588/3710053

Comment: Hi Siebe, thank you very much for your reply, unfortunately, your code did not work but the one from Forensic_07 works!

Comment: I assume the wrong quotes were the problem:  It should have been: //a[text()[contains(.,'Archiv')]] or with double quotes //a[text()[contains(.,"Archiv")]]

Comment: Hi Siebe, yup, confirmed, the quotes were the problem, now it is working fine! :-) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the linked answer above, `contains()` takes a single string as a first argument, but `text()` is a selector that returns a set of text nodes. Since `contains()` can't take a set, it evaluates against the *first* node in the set, which isn't actually the `\nArchiv dokumentů\n` text, but a single newline character between the `a` and `i` tags, so it doesn't match.

You can use `//a[contains(., "Archiv")]` to evaluate `a` as a string, which will use all the text in the `a` tag.

Comment: Hi Forensic_07 thank you! This is working! I am now a bit more experienced with xpaths thanks to you :-)