# Xpath find an element containing text within the scope of a parent element

Tags: javascript, testing, xpath, web-deployment

Hello I have a parent element with the ID contacts that element has a child element that contains the text "hello" I would like to find that child element as a child of the element having the ID contacts. This is because "hello" occur on several places on the page but I only the want the "hello" that has contacts as parent.

Example of what I mean:

```
"//*[@id='contacts']/[contains(text(),'hello')]"
```

This does not work sadly

Comment: Share the HTML or URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work! the easiest way to try this live, is in Chromes dev tools.

```
//*[@id='latest_block']//*[text()[contains(.,'hello')]]
```

Find out more how Xpath works here:

[XPath contains(text(),'some string') doesn't work when used with node with more than one Text subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a tag name for the child element, so just change your XPath to

```
"//*[@id='contacts']/*[contains(text(),'hello')]"
```

In case the child element is not a direct child of `//*[@id='contacts']` element your XPath should be

```
"//*[@id='contacts']//*[contains(text(),'hello')]"
```