# lxml.html XPATH expression for element when the test has to be applied to the text_content not the text

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing, xpath-1.0, lxml.html

I have the following html

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
    <a name="_marker_1"></a>
    <a name="bananabread"></a>
    <font style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
      <a name="bananabread"></a>Ban</font>     <font style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">ana Bread</font>
  </p>
  <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:10pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">The Best You Ever Tasted</p>
  <p style="margin-top:24pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:7.69%;font-style:italic;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">If you don't agree that this is the best banana bread you have ever eaten well I would suggest you see your doctor</p>
  <p style="margin-top:10pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:7.69%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">Lots of text here describing what I am trying to capture</p>
  <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
    <a name="_marker_2"></a>
    <a name="bananapudding"></a>
    <font style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
      <a name="bananapudding"></a>Banana</font>
    <font style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">Pudding</font>
  </p>
  <p style="text-align:center;margin-top:10pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-weight:bold;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">Creamy and Satisfying</p>
  <p style="margin-top:24pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:7.69%;font-style:italic;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">This is the same recipe your mother used when you were ten!</p>
  <p style="margin-top:10pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:7.69%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">Lots of text here describing what I am trying to capture</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to write an xpath expression to identify Banana Bread - my initial efforts were successful -

```
b_tree.xpath('.//*[starts-with(text(),"Banana Bread")]')
```

but I notice the error cases and upon investigation they are like the html above - another element is added inside the content I am searching for.  Sometimes it is like above, a possibly unneeded font element, sometimes it is an anchor.

I worked with this answer ([Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more)) but have not been successful

I can check for elements that have text_content() - clean up the text_content and then string match to my ultimate goal but I am hoping to learn to better apply xpath to these types of problems.

To be absolutely clear I need the text_content of the p element.  But sometimes I just need the text of a font element.  My existing XPATH expression works fine on the cases where there is not an intervening element.  I do not know when I open the page the structure that was imposed on the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `text()` expression is applied to an element whose text content is interrupted by other elements, it returns a nodeset consisting of multiple *text nodes*, of which `starts-with` considers only the first. If you replace `text()` by `.`, you get the *text value* of the element, which is the concatenation of all text nodes, and that's what you want.

But there is still a problem with the spaces in an element like (attributes omitted, spaces are dots):

```html
<p>
..<a></a>
..<a></a>
..<font>
....<a></a>Banana</font>
..<font>Pudding</font>
</p>
```

The text value of this element is `_.._.._.._....Banana_..Pudding_` (underscores represent line feeds), therefore you must apply `normalize-space`, which normalizes this to `Banana.Pudding`, so that

```
.//*[starts-with(normalize-space(.),"Banana Pudding")]
```

finds this occurrence.

However, `Banana Bread` cannot be found, because it does not exist on the page. The element

```html
<font>
..<a></a>Ban</font>.....<font>ana.Bread</font>
```

has a normalized text value of `Ban.ana.Bread` and you don't expect the space inside the word `Banana`. `normalize-space` removes spaces and line feeds that are invisible on the rendered page, but the two spaces in `Ban.ana.Bread` are both visible.

If there was no space between the two `<font>` elements,

```
.//*[starts-with(normalize-space(.),"Banana Bread")]
```

would detect 3 elements: the `<html>`, the `<body>` and the `<p>`, because "Banana Bread" are the first words in each of them. So you might better use

```
.//p[starts-with(normalize-space(.),"Banana Bread")]
```

instead.