# How to click an element that contains visible text and is clickable with Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The element to be clicked based ONLY on the text it contains (others):

```
<a class="blah" href="/some_page/"><span>15</span> others</a>
```

The item that fails:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), ' others')]").click()
```

The error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'others')]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An additional alternative from DebanjanB's answer using a different xpath inspired from [XPath contains(text(),'some string') doesn't work when used with node with more than one Text subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more)

```
"//*[text()[contains(.,' others')]]"
```

Comment: "//*[text()='others']" works too which I found by trial and error + studying xpath. Thanks for answering with diligence.

Answer (score 1):

To locate the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.blah[href='/some_page/'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='blah' and @href='/some_page/'][contains(., 'others')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)