# Get child element from complicated xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

So I have some complicated situation in the DOM where I need to create XPath and get its child element. I have the following XPath

```
((//p[contains(text(),'" + read_contract_title() + "')]/parent::div/parent::div)[2]//button)[2]
```

The above is basically a ... more options button, that I need to click and then click the child element inside of it.

How do I get about getting the child element (button) inside the above XPath?

Looking forward to your help and reply.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the HTML you'll be querying? Posting an xpath with no context isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case parent element can be located with this XPath

```
"((//p[contains(text(),'" + read_contract_title() + "')]/parent::div/parent::div)[2]//button)[2]"
```

The `button` element inside it could be simply located with

```
"((//p[contains(text(),'" + read_contract_title() + "')]/parent::div/parent::div)[2]//button)[2]//button"
```

In case this is the only `button` element inside that parent element

Comment: this is good answer. It helped me reach the solution. so I have to go had few more parents and then get the child element. Will accept an answer in 5 mins once SO allows it :) thank you @prophet

Comment: You should warn OP about the [perils of using `contains(text(),"substring")` and the better solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085).  Also, advise OP to post the subject markup so that we can explain such issues (and probably suggest a cleaner XPath too) in concrete terms.

Comment: @kjhughes sure, but since he did not provide more details I could base my answer only on details OP shared in the question

Comment: OP appears to be happy, but it won't last if the targeted text shifts out of position one.  Future readers deserve the warning too anytime the problematic `contains(text(), "substring")` construct appears in a question (or an answer).

Comment: Again, you are right @kjhughes, but since this question is about `selenium` and `xpath` only XPath 1.0 is relevant here, so there is no really need to worry about issues with Xpath 2.0+ in this case.

Comment: You may be missing the more import part of the point.  The `contains(text(), "substring")` construct is more dangerous under XPath 1.0 than 2.0 because under 1.0 it ***silently only considers the first text node***; at least under XPath 2.0 it's an impossible-to-miss error.  See [my full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085) for further explanation and details.

Comment: I read it today (again). Maybe I just did not understood the entire deepness of that. My XPath knowledge is really much much less than yours since my actual XPath experience is limited with locating elements on a web page for Selenium uses only :)
I hope your answers (including the one you linked to here) and notes will be useful to as many people as possible.