# How to solve "not a valid XPath expression" error in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath, cypress

I used this string to find an element:

```
cy.xpath('//*[text()="search ${keyword}")]')
```

And when I run my test, it shows me the right result in console but also it shows me this error:

> Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string `'//*[text()="search ${keyword}")]'` is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

I used contains and it works.
there is an icon in my XPath and it couldn't find just the text.

```
cy.xpath(`//*[contains(text(), 'search ${keyword}')]`)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Issue with your original question

The actual syntax error is due to an extraneous `)`:

```
cy.xpath('//*[text()="search ${keyword}")]')
                                        ^
```

Delete that character to eliminate the syntax error.

### Issue with your [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584016/290085)

Your solution,

```
cy.xpath(`//*[contains(text(), 'search ${keyword}')]`)
```

doesn't do what you likely think it does.  (It's only checking for substrings within the *first* `text()` node child of every element.)  For full details, see [this extensive explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)

Instead, use

```
cy.xpath(`//*[text()[contains(., 'search ${keyword}')]]`)
```

or the other variation shown in the linked explanation per your requirements.